# How to copy data from one row to another in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So I have a table named `customers` and in that table there are places where the column `zip` is filled out, but column `state` is not.

We can reasonably assume that if we have another customer with both the `zip` and the `state` column filled, and the `zip` matches a customer without the `state` filled, that the customer without `state` filled can have it filled with the same value as the other matching customer.

The goal is to fill in the missing values when we know them in another row.

**Example:**

```
       BEFORE:                         AFTER:
/====================\         /====================\
| id | zip   | state |         | id | zip   | state |
|----|-------|-------|         |----|-------|-------|
| 0  | 12345 | FL    |   ==>   | 0  | 12345 | FL    |
| 1  | 67890 | CA    |   ==>   | 1  | 67890 | CA    |
| 2  | 67890 |       |   ==>   | 2  | 67890 | CA    |
| 3  | 12345 |       |         | 3  | 12345 | FL    |
| 4  | 10101 |       |         | 4  | 10101 |       |
\====================/         \====================/
```

**My Question:** How can I use MySQL to update the table and fill in the missing data from another row?

So far I have the SQL for finding the missing values:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE country = 'united states' 
    AND (zip <> '' OR zip IS NOT NULL) 
    AND (state = '' OR state IS NULL)
```

Comment: do you need to `update` the table or you just need a `select`?

Comment: I need to update the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
UPDATE customers 

INNER JOIN customers AS updateValues ON updateValues.zip = customers.zip AND updateValues.state IS NOT NULL AND updateValues.state != ''

SET customers.state = updateValues.state

WHERE (customers.zip <> '' AND customers.zip IS NOT NULL) 
AND (customers.state = '' OR customers.state IS NULL)
```

(not sure where `WHERE country = 'united states'` was coming from, so I removed it)

Comment: The country has to be specified because the database in question is heavily polluted.

Answer (score 2):

you can use update and inner join

```
update my_table as a
inner join source_table as b on  a.zip = b.zip 
set a.state = b.state 
where b.state is not null
or b.state = ''
AND country = 'united states' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ZIP_code_prefixes

The first 3 digits of a zip code indicate the state it is in.  I'd do some logic based on that.

Edit: This doesn't have to be too complex

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS
SET STATE = CASE
                WHEN SUBSTRING(zip, 1,3) IN ('448','449', ect....) THEN 'OH'
                ....
                ....
            END
WHERE STATE IS NULL
```

Comment: While you are right this is overall a better idea, I have a limited amount of time, and this would extremely verbose SQL. +1

Comment: I've edited it to reflect what I'm saying better, since that wasn't an acceptable answer apparently

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about performance but you should be able to:

```
update table_name tn1
   set tn1.state = (select max(tn2.state) from table_name tn2 where tn2.zip = tn1.zip and tn2.state is not null)
 where tn1.state is null
```